# Remote desktop through a Mac's ICS to Windows host

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, ics

Okay so long story short, I access the interwebs like this:
university wifi (cant change routing seetings) -> MacBook -> Windows machine using ICS over ethernet (Cat5 cable)

Having a monitor and my laptop on my desk leaves me with little space so I want to remote desktop from my mac to the Windows machine using the ICS. I can't figure this out, can somebody lend a hand?

Comment: ? http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=18140

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't see that, I was using Azure's app. And it works just great now

Comment: I am glad that this is what you need. Thank you to describe the results. Good Luck!